# Android Prevent Writing In Clipboard

Tags: android, security, keyboard

I want to ask if I could prevent writing in clipboard file in android using permission or some configuration without using a `ClipboardManager`. I was confused when knowing that all text automatically saved in the clipboard file and I have sensitive data. I will be glued if there is a way to prevent writing in the clipboard.

Comment: Android 10 introduced new security behavior that prevents background apps from accessing clipboard manager. Only exception is users default input application (keyboard). As for older android versions not sure if anything can be done, especially if you're not writing the OS itself.

Comment: My app supports an old version and I'm warned from anyone who can read all sensitive data from the clipboard

Comment: `knowing that all text automatically saved in the clipboard`? Which text? And when? By who?  I have never seen such automatic save. Please explain

Comment: any text that is written in edit text like email, password, or credit card number. it will be saved by the system.